# How to bulk upload media files and set each item's template to custom template?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
-- Folder 1
---- Folder 2
------- File 1
---- Folder 3
------- File 1
```

And so on with Folder 1 being the parent folder. When I upload the files from zip, they are uploaded and have their template set as their file extension (docx, pdf, etc.) but I would like to upload them just as a File type with custom fields. I created a custom template that is based on the System/media/File template but then how can I apply that to all those files without going into each one and doing it? It would take a long time to do it manually.

Comment: Consider using `Set-ItemTemplate` to change the template after the media item is uploaded. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/how-to-change-item-templates-and-retain-existing-data

Comment: Do you want to save docx, pdf and etc as a file just during an uploading zip file or each media with this extension should always be stored as the file? 
How do you upload a zip package? Using a default media libriary interface?