# Change field from General Link to Single line text and retain Text

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm having a similar issue with the one described here:
[How to change item templates and retain existing data](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/how-to-change-item-templates-and-retain-existing-data)

```
Template_Old 
Title        General Link



Template_New
Title        Single-line text
```

My problem is that before I change the datasource item template from Template_Old to Template_New, I have to extract the text from General Link field and place it into the Single-Line text.
Any piece of ps script would be helpful.
Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code. Not sure how we can use the `Set-ItemTemplate` and `-FieldsToCopy` but using the old method we sure can achieve this :

```
$rootItem = Get-Item -path "Item path"
$targetTemplate = Get-Item "TemplateId or Path here";
# Template_Old_Link is the old field in old template - General Link
# Template_New_Title is the new field in new template - Single Line Text
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$field = $rootItem.Fields["Template_Old_Link"]
$fieldValue = $field.Text
$rootItem.ChangeTemplate($targetTemplate);
$updatedItem = Get-Item $rootItem.ID;
$updatedItem.Template_New_Title = $fieldValue;
```

Check this and let me know if this script works.